# Bitbucket users left organisation, I want to know implications on code if i delete users from my account

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have some users in bit bucket cloud who left organisation, I want to remove them from my account so I can save billing.

My question is if I remove access will there be any problem with commits and work they have contributed to the projects or repositories over the time?

I have already tried checking on their site, but there is nothing mentioned specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Commit history will not be affected (unless you, or somebody else on your team, rewrites it). The users in question will still have any previous copies of the repo they'd cloned or downloaded, but they will no longer be able to connect to push or pull or read code in the GUI.